# I want to load an html version of my resume for my website. But its failing to compile

Tags: html, reactjs

```
import ResumeHTML from "resume.html"

const ReactComponent = () => {
   return (<a href={ResumeHTML}>View Resume</a>)
}
```

Failed to compile

./src/assets/resume.html 1:0
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders

Comment: Are you using `create-react-app`?

Comment: are you trying to parse Html or the Html page?

Comment: this really seems strange;  if `resume.html` is an HTML file, then you would want the `href` to point to the **location** of the file, not the **contents** of the file....  i.e. "`href="this is the text from the resume....`" wouldn't really be valid.  On top of that, importing HTML content into a JavaScript class isn't really right either....

Answer (score 0):

The error happens because Webpack does not know how to handle import of `.html` files inside your javascript module.

If you have a webpack configuration in your project you can add a loader for html files, probably the [file-loader](https://webpack.js.org/loaders/file-loader/) that copies your file in the public directory and replace it with a link inside your javascript module.

If you do not have access to your webpack configuration (ex. if you're using a non ejected version of Create React App), you should instead make your html file public and hardcode the link in your javascript module without importing the file.